# magento install script 1.8.1

Tags: magento, installation

I'm trying to create a symply module for import country region and more in database.It's very simple but the data wasn't import.I can't figure why:

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Province_Italian>
            <version>1.0.50</version>
        </Province_Italian>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <province_italian_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Province_Italian</module>
                    <class>Province_Italian_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
              </setup>
                 <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </province_italian_setup>

             <province_italian_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
             </province_italian_write>
             <province_italian_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
             </province_italian_read>

       </resources>

    </global>
</config>
```

basic configuration file

and i had this folder structure with install script

Province/Italian/Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
             data/province_italian_setup/data-install-x.x.x.php
```

and usually file in etc folder for configurazion config.xml
It' very simple ,the module is added because i've seen this reference in core_resource table, but seem that can't read installation file from data folder.
Where's mistake?
I'm going mad!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
"because i've seen this reference in core_resource"
```

Dalete that reference record from core_resource, delete cache, and try again

Comment: the problem that i seen was about a data folder, i move all the script to sql old style installer and go like a charm.Thak you

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- Make sure that have your module enabled, by having a file in `app/etc/modules/Province_Italian.xml` stating the following information:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
      <modules>
         <Province_Italian>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><!-- Put your Module dependencies here --></depends> 
         </Province_Italian>
      </modules>
  </config>
  ```
- The code of the module can be found in `app/code/local/Province_Italian`
- The first install file matches the version number of the module. In this case that would be  1.0.50. So the filename must be

  ```
  app/code/local/Province_Italian/data/province_italian_setup/data-install-10.0.50.php
  ```
- Once the install script has ran, it cannot run again. Make sure that the code `province_italian_setup` is absent in the database table `core_resource`. This will trigger Magento to run the setup script.
- Have logging (`Mage::log(...)`) in your datat install script to see it the script runs.
- When you have no custom setup functionality, then the `Province_Italian_Model_Resource_Setup`.
- I also noticed that the `models` is missing in your XML. Probably your need to add it. Based upon your description, you probably need (1) a model to to manipulate a datastore purely through PHP code, and (2) need a resource model to import the data into a custom database table.

  ```
  <config>
      <modules>
          <Province_Italian>
              <version>1.0.50</version>
          </Province_Italian>
      </modules>
      <global>
          <models>
              <province_italian>
                  <class>Province_Italian_Model</class>
                  <resourceModel>province_italian_resource</resourceModel>
              </province_italian>
              <province_italian_resource>
                  <class>Province_Italian_Model_Resource</class>
                  <entities>
                      <!-- Put your entities here -->
                  </entities>
              </province_italian_resource>
          </models>
          <resources>
              <province_italian_setup>
                  <setup>
                      <module>Province_Italian</module>
                      <!-- <class>Province_Italian_Model_Resource_Setup</class> -->
                  </setup>
              </province_italian_setup>
              <province_italian_write>
                  <connection>
                      <use>core_write</use>
                  </connection>
              </province_italian_write>
              <province_italian_read>
                  <connection>
                      <use>core_read</use>
                  </connection>
              </province_italian_read>
          </resources>
     </global>
  ```

I hope the above will help.

Comment: Thank! ,it's very exhaustive